# 2 последовательных запроса в YII2 в методе

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Приветствую всех вошедших )

Вообщем есть API метод в моем сайте на YII2, в методе есть запрос, все работает все круто. Решил добавить в этом же методе еще один запрос, причем после первого. Итог - первый запрос не выполняется

Господа, прошу объяснить как реализовать 2 ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНЫХ запроса

```html
class PostController extends Controller{
  
  //метод API. в котором надо выполнить 2 запроса
  public function actionPageview(){
    
    $return   = '{"status":"error"}';
    
    $sql1 = "SELECT ..";
  $model = $this->sqlrun([$sql1]);
    
    if($model['myfield1']=='Что то важное'){
      
      $return   = '{"status":"ok"}';
      
      if($model['myfield2']=='Что то ОЧЕНЬ важное'){
        
        $return   = '{"status":"error"}';
        
        $sql2 = "UPDATE/DELETE ..";
        //$this->sqlrun([$sql2]);//вот тут валится все!
        
      }
      
    }
    
    return $return;
    
  }
  
  //метод который выполняет ТОЛЬКО MySQL запросы
  public function sqlrun($array){
  $sql = $array[0];
  $connection = \Yii::$app->db;
  $model = $connection->createCommand($sql);
  $model = $model->queryOne();//queryAll
  return $model;
 }
}
```

Comment: Что говорят логи ?

Comment: Exception (Database Exception) 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error
The SQL being executed was: UPDATE .. мой запрос' 

in C:\My\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\mysite.local\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php:636

есть выполнить запросы которые я делаю отдельно, то ошибок нет. Загадка для меня именно в этом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод queryOne() запрашивает данные и срабатывает в случае если запрос SELECT ....
Если вы обновляете или удаляете данные, вам необходимо использовать

```
$model->execute();
```

вместо

```
$model->queryOne()
```

Comment: И еще совет, не знаю почему вы используете чистый sql если в yii2 есть замечательный ActiveRecord и зачем вы передаете запрос в метод  sqlrun() массивом и потом принимаете его опять нулевым значением массива ?? проще тогда передавать его как строку !

Comment: совет учту, спасибо. Пример привел в упрощенном виде, что бы можно было прочесть